# Coloring textbox red on validationerror when loading form

Tags: c#, wpf

Well, the tooltip that is supposed to show the error works...but I have an adorned element that is supposed to color the border red.  This doesn't work - it only does when I actually edit the textbox itself.  When I load the wpf form, I want all empty textboxes to be red until the user enters valid data.  How do I do this?

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Is the Binding is of that `Textbox` is done with `PropertyChanged` or what?

Comment: Question too textual ,
Give us what you tried 
Or **Hire Developers**

Answer (score 0):

Write this, in the Load event handler of your form :

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is TextBox)
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text))
         ((TextBox)c).Background = Brushes.Blue; // Setting the background-color of the empty TextBoxes
}
```

*(If you are looking for sth else, tell in comment)*